# Is there some kind of virtual DB in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi

I'm running a python script on a read only system. Because I'm dealing with a lot of files I want to have some kind of database. But since it's read only I just need that in ram. I could safe all the information in variables, but I'd love to be able to query in a more complex way. So is there a trick to get something like a mysql database, but not saving in to the memory card?

I know I could create a tmpfs, but maybe there is a more clever way!?

I'm running Raspbian (like Debian) on my raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)!  Use it pretty much just like you would use MySQL, except that you can run it entirely in memory with no setup or configuration hassles.

When you create a "connection" object to a MySQL database you are actually reaching out over the network and connecting to a remote resource, but when you create a "connection" object in sqlite, that creates the (single-user-at-a-time) database on the fly and does not access external resources.

Comment: Are the queries the same? At the first glance it looks like it.

Comment: @JasonTS: It is SQL, yes.  There are no doubt some MySQL-specific things that won't work, but basic SQL stuff is the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question: Do I need to worry about a connection timeout when just using the db in memory?

Comment: @JasonTS No, you do not.  The "connection" is virtual; there is not actually any server to time out a connection, there is only the memory block and a protocol for accessing it inside the host process via SQL.